# Алфавитные срезы

Tags: python-3.x, строки

Нужна помощь. Помогите нащупать правильный алгоритм решения задания.

Задание:

Дана строка s = 'pqrsxdef' (строка может быть любой) в этой строке есть две подстроки, которые сохраняют последовательность в алфавите: pqrs и def. Нужно найти их, перевернуть и "вставить обратно" так чтобы получилась  "srqpxfed"

Строки могут быть любыми, могут не содержать фрагментов алфавита, могут содержать их несколько, они могут быть произвольной длинны...

Пробовал:

```
from icecream import ic # такой вывод мне нравится больше чем стандартный print
from string import ascii_lowercase

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i:] in ascii_lowercase:
        ic(s[i:])
        ic(s[:i] + s[i:][::-1])
        break
```

но очевидно, что это решение не подходит...

Подскажите "в какую сторону" думать?

нарезать s на все возможные комбинации и проверять их на наличие в ascii_lowercase?
нарезать ascii_lowercase на все возможные комбинации и проверить их наличие в s?
но это же будет долго, нудно и не оптимально.

как тогда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь пойти простым путём, но когда вы делаете срез и проверяете его через `in` на вхождение, получается сложность O(n<sup>2</sup>). А если делать комбинации (а это уже O(n<sup>2</sup>)) и проверять их через `in` на вхождение, то это вообще O(n<sup>3</sup>) получится.

Судя по всему, тут нужно думать так.

- Что нам нужно найти? Возрастающие (на 1) последовательности букв.
- Что такое возрастающая (на 1) последовательность букв? Это последовательность, в которой код следующего символа на 1 больше кода предыдущего символа.
- Как получить сложность алгоритма O(n)? Нужно идти по строке последовательно в один проход и анализировать её.

Таким образом, ближе к алгоритму:

- Будем накапливать найденные последовательности вида (индекс начала, индекс конца [может ещё +1 чтобы сразу готовый срез был]) в списке `sequences`.
- Заведём булеву переменную `in_sequence`, показывающую, копим мы уже последовательность или ещё не нашли ничего.
- Ну и дальше нужно идти по строке, смотреть, отличается ли код следующего символа на 1 от предыдущего (в бОльшую сторону) и какое у нас значение `in_sequence` и обрабатывать 4 возможных получающихся варианта.
- Запоминать начало последовательности, если найдено её начало. в переменной `start`.
- Когда заканчивается очередная последовательность - добавлять её в наш список `sequences`.
- Когда закончится разбор строки, ещё раз проверить значение `in_sequence` и если оно `True`, то не забыть добавить последнюю последовательность в наш список.
- В конце алгоритма идём по списку `sequences`, выводим неизменные части строки (это с конца предыдущей последовательности до начала новой) и перевёрнутые - это сама очередная последовательность, перевёрнутая.
- Не забыть вывести конец строки от конца последней последовательности.

Как вариант - можно скидывать в список и последовательности и не-последовательности (с каким-то признаком). Потом проще будет выводить что получилось.

Answer (score 3):

`gen` сверяет пары последовательных символов. Если они не по порядку в алфавите, предыдущий фрагмент строки выдаётся наружу. `revolver` все фрагменты переворачивает и склеивает в строку:

```
import string


def pairs(s):
    """ 'abcd' -> ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd') """
    it = iter(s)
    next(it, None)
    return zip(s, it)


# {('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ..., ('x', 'y'), ('y', 'z')}
alphabet_pairs = set(pairs(string.ascii_lowercase))


def revolver(s):

    def gen():
        """ 'pqrsxdef' -> 'pqrs', 'x', 'def' """
        i = 0
        for j, p in enumerate(pairs(s), start=1):
            if p not in alphabet_pairs:
                yield s[i:j]
                i = j
        yield s[i:]

    return ''.join(s[::-1] for s in gen())


print(revolver(input()))
```

> ```
> $ echo pqrsxdef | python revolver.py
> srqpxfed
> ```

Comment: Идея со словарём хорошая. И коды символов не нужно брать )

Comment: @CrazyElf, переделал словарь на множество пар.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь и подсказки, друзья.

CrazyElf - это тот случай когда после подсказки хлопаешь себя по лбу и говоришь: "точно, ну как я сам до этого не додумался"

Stanislav Volodarskiy - красивое и изячное решение, до которого я не додумался, спасибо.

Мое решение было таким:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as abc

def solution(s):
    word = s[0]
    ans = []
    for i in s[1:]:
        if word + i in abc:
            word += i
        else:
            ans += [word]
            word = i

    ans = ans + [word]


    result = ''
    for i in ans:
        if len(i) > 1 and i in abc:
            result += i[::-1]
        else:
            result += i

    return result
```

Не такое красивое и изящное, громоздкое и не оптимизированное, но тоже подошло...